# Calling the class isn't running the methods

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to animate an object across the screen in `pygame` using a class.

I have tried this without the class and works just fine, but with the class it doesn't work.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.locx = 20
        self.locy = 90
        self.x = 20
        self.y = 90

    def draw_car(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, [self.locx, self.locy], 20, 8)

    def animator(self):
        self.locx += 5


def main_game():  # main game loop, for all code related to the simulation
    game_play = False
    while not game_play:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_play = True
                pygame.quit()

        clock.tick(60)
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, BLUE, [1, 450], [800, 450], 5)
        draw_road()
        Car()
```

Draw a circle and animate it across screen with a class.

Comment: All you're doing is creating new instances of `Car`s. You should create one outside the loop, and then call that instance's `draw_car()` method inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Car()` just creates a `Car` object. It isn't drawn or moved until you call `Car.draw_car` or `Car.animator`. What you need to do is to create the `Car` object before the `while` loop and assign it to a variable `my_car` say. To draw and move the car you then need to call `my_car.animator()` and `my_car.draw_car` in the `while`-loop, i.e.

```
def main_game():  # main game loop, for all code related to the simulation
    game_play = False
    my_car = Car()
    while not game_play:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_play = True
                pygame.quit()

        clock.tick(60)
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, BLUE, [1, 450], [800, 450], 5)
        draw_road()
        my_car.animator()
        my_car.draw_car()
```